# how to get raw mjpg stream from webcam

Tags: c++, opencv, winapi, webcam, video-capture

I have logitech webcam, which streams 1080p@30fps using MJPG compression via USB2.0. I need to write this raw stream to hard drive or send via network. I do NOT need to decompress it. OpenCV gives me decompressed frames, so i need to compress them back. This leads to heavy CPU utilization waste. How to get raw MJPEG stream instead as it comes from camera? (Windows 7, Visual Studio, C++)

Comment: Addition: In my case data can stay in kernel space. I just need to transfer it from usb webcam driver to filesystem/network io driver, with lowest possible cpu overhead and latency. Even if this assumes exclusive camera access. Has this been done before? Is there some working example?

Answer (score 1):

Windows native video capture related APIs DirectShow and Media Foundation let you capture video from a webcam in original format. It is a natural task for these APIs and is done in a straightforward way (specifically, if a web camera gets hardware compressed M-JPEG feed, you can have that programmatically).

- [About Video Capture in DirectShow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373406)
- [Audio/Video Capture in Media Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317912)

You are free to do whatever you want with the data afterwards: decompress, send over network, compose a Motion JPEG over HTTP response feed etc.